# Умножить каждый элемент массива через LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Есть массив, нужно каждый элемент умножить, что бы каждый элемент массива получил свое новое значение.

Да, я могу через foreach по нему пройти, но можно ли это сделать через LINQ?

Как я понимаю, на массиве нужно выполнить ToList, а затем ForEach и выполнить умножение?

Comment: Linq - язык запросов, изменять коллекции с помощью него нельзя, можно получить только новую. Можно реализовать свой метод расширения, делающий это, но это плохой тон - пользователи вашего метода могут не ожидать что исходная коллекция изменится!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Легко.

```
var multiple = 5; //x5 например
var result = arr.Select(x => x * multiple); //ToList() опционально если уж совсем не терпится материализовать результат.
```

Comment: Да, но в таком случае мы получим новую коллекцию, на сколько я знаю, а без новых коллекций можно?

Comment: В этом и суть LINQ и всего функционального подхода. Привыкайте. Это на самом деле огромное преимущество.

Comment: Сергей, а если абстрагировать от LINQ, нет ли методов операции над всеми элементами массива без создания нового массива?

Comment: Если хотите по старинке - делайте по старинке, цикл и все такие дела.

Comment: И кстати, по возможности не делайте ToList().ForEach() - в некоторых случаях два раза коллекцию пробегать будет - тупая работа. Лучше написать метод расширения для IEnumerable или обычным foreach пройтись.

Comment: А почему избегаете создания новых коллекций? Я понимаю, что памяти жрет чуть больше - но в наше время это не часто настолько критично, чтобы пренебрегать читаемостью и чистотой кода.

Comment: Просто, не люблю расходовать ресурсы, где можно обойтись без этого.

Comment: Учитывая ленивую природу LINQа при правильном приготовлении оверхед не такой уж и большой как может показаться, а в свете значительного снижения трудозатрат и возможностей для ошибки - это вы зря. К тому же - предварительные оптимизации - зло)

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно создавать новую коллекцию - изменяйте существующую:

```
    List<int> nums = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    nums = nums.Select(x => x * 2).ToList();
```